# Start app by scanning qr code

Tags: android, qr-code, launch

How can I start my app by scanning a qr code?

I found this:
[Android start application from QR Code with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258633/android-start-application-from-qr-code-with-params)

The answer is not all clear to me.

```
<data android:scheme="myApp" android:host="org.hardartcore.myApp" android:path="/"/>
```

I suppose myApp has to ve replaced by the name of my app, and org.hardartcore is the package name? After creating a qr-code of either of these strings and scan it (using xzing's scanner), the only sensible option is to open to scanned string with a web browser. The webbrowser on it's turn simply can't find the string.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in this case you are trying to declare that the following URI will open your app:

`myApp://org.hardartcore.myApp/`

Then you `VIEW` that URI from another app using an `Intent`. You could put this in a QR code, and hopefully a reader will do that bit for you when it's scanned.

Comment: You are right, it is the QR scanner which doesn't support launching the app directly. When entering in a browser it works. I created a workaround in which the qr code contains a web url and the webpage redirects to myApp:// which launches the app.