# How to open another activity after scanning a QR code?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on QR code scanner. I want to ask if it is possible to open another activity after the QR code have been scanned rather than getting it displayed as a toast?

I've solved the problem already .Thank you guys, I'm sorry for asking for such a simple question. I'm really new to android programming.

```
public void scanResult(ScanResult result) {

      Toast.makeText(this, result.getRawResult().getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```

Comment: Then what is problem? have you tried to start Activity in `scanResult ` ?

Comment: Use `Intent` and start another activity

Comment: Are you getting any error??? If not then just use intent to start a new Activity.

Comment: take a look at this questions this might help you ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831050/android-how-to-read-qr-code-in-my-application
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258633/android-start-application-from-qr-code-with-params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? What seems to be the problem? In which file is your **scanResult** located/ do you have access to the **Context**?

As normal just use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, StartThisActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```